# AngularJS | Set Path Parmeter while using $http.get method

Tags: angularjs

I have a GET endpoint with URI as /user/user-id . The 'user-id' is the path variable here.

How can I set the path variable while making the GET request?

This is what I tried:-

```
$http.get('/user/:id',{
                params: {id:key}
            });
```

Instead of replacing the path variable, the id get appended as query param. 
i.e my debugger show the request URL as `'http://localhost:8080/user/:id?id=test'`

My expected resolved URL should be like 'http://localhost:8080/user/test'

Comment: Found this blog helpful for understanding $resource - http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/consuming-restful-apis.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$http's params object is meant for query strings, so key-value pairs you pass into params are output as query string keys and values.

```
$http.get('/user', {
    params: { id: "test" }
});
```

Becomes: `http://localhost:8080/user?id=test`

If you need `http://localhost:8080/user/test`, you can either:

1. Construct the url yourself,

   `$http.get('/user/' + id);`
2. Or, use $resource (specifically $resource.get https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). This is a little cleaner.

Comment: Looking at the example in the shared link, what does @id part means?  var CreditCard = $resource('/user/:userId/card/:cardId',
 {userId:123, cardId:'@id'}, {
  charge: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}}
 });

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this?:

```
var path = 'test';
$http.get('/user/' + path, {});
```

Comment: Yes that's definitely a way. I was looking to avoid that concat part as it looks untidy when we have multiple path params. For example: /user/:id/account/:accountId/transaction/:txnid

Comment: I see... Then perhaps you could use `$resorce` (as @user2943490 suggests...).